# Enabling FTP functions in existing PHP install

Tags: php

I know that when installing PHP you use `--enable-ftp` in the command line to enable FTP.

But if I have a PHP install that doesn't have FTP support and I want to add it, is there a way? Something in PHP.INI?

Or do I need to simply reinstall?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as of this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/ftp.installation.php) you have to add this to your php.ini:

```
extension=php_ftp.dll
```

Comment: Where am I adding this?

Comment: sry. This goes in php ini, anywhere. Check if extension= something is already there and put it after that

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib

if you want to do sFTP without enabling the ssh2 extension.